# Form select option to change what gets rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 4 form with a drop down selection. If Multiple Choice is selected I want to render a page. If True/False is selected I want to render a different page.

I do not know why this isn't working, My javascript knowledge is bad:

```
<h1>New question</h1>

<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/error_questions' %>

<%= render 'form', f: f %>

<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
<div id="mcanswers" style="display:none">
<h1>Answers</h1>
<%= render 'four_answers', :f => builder %>
<%= f.submit "Create Question", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>

<div id="tfanswers" style="display:none">
<h1>Answers</h1>
<%= render 'tf_answers', :f => builder %>
<%= f.submit "Create Question", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

<hr />

<%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>

<script>

function checkType() {
    if ($('#question_question_type').val('MC'))
    {
        $('#mcanswers').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else if ($('#question_question_type').val('TF'))
    {
        $('#tfanswers').css('display', 'block');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$('select#question_question_type').on('change', function() {
    checkType();
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: what isn't working about it? what is it doing instead of what you expect?

Comment: It does not show or hide the divs. I get , unexpected end of input on line 1

Comment: nothing jumps out at me, perhaps you should try making a jsfiddle, although one thing to note is that I do not believe .val() works as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is rendered from the beginning. The div is just hiding it. I had to use controller logic to decide when to render.